# How to pull toothbrush out of the sink?

Tags: plumbing

My toddler dropped a toothbrush down a bathroom sink.  Unfortunately, the stopper wasn't in the sink at the time.

When looking down from above the sink, I believe the toothbrush is in the PVC section of the picture, and leaning against the side.  The PVC is a larger diameter so even if I could reach the toothbrush from above, I'd need to pull it center before pulling up.

How do I remove the toothbrush and get the sink functional again?

[image: Under the Sink]
[image: Under the Sink with bottom of trap]

Comment: Can you include a photo of the entire trap (the loopy part of the drain). Usually traps are designed to be taken apart for cleaning, and/or retrieving dropped items.

Comment: ..it looks like some landscaper just MacGyver'd the p-trap assembly out of spare parts and solvent. lol

Comment: Can you see the toothbrush down the drain?  Looks like it travelled pretty far.  If so, you can construct a small hook like contraption out of a wire hanger.  Ideally the bristles are up and you can make a small circle on the end, then flatten 90 degrees and wrap it around and grab it and lift up.

Comment: @Tester101 added a picture with bottom of trap.

Comment: @treeNinja Yes I can see it, but the bristle side is down.  I haven't tried a wire hanger yet, but that's an interesting suggestion, thanks!

Comment: if the bristles were up it might have been easier to "snag". If you remove the plug at the bottom can you snake it through?  Either grab or push further down to the opening?  Remember to put a plastic tub underneath to catch the water in the trap.

Answer (score 5):

In my part of the world, PVC P-traps for sinks and basins are universally designed so that you can easily remove the U-bend from below without tools.

[image]

I wouldn't hesitate very long before undoing all the obvious nuts visible in your picture† and attempting to gain access to the U-bend.

In some cases a strap-wrench may be useful, but usually those joints between PVC sections are sealed by a simple rubber ring and shouldn't have any kind of putty or sealant applied (which can make them hard to remove by hand)

[image]

<sub>*† Obviously, except the one on the flexible tap connector(s)!*</sub>

Comment: Same is true in my part of the world, but as @elrobis notes, this one looks (from what we can see in the picture) like a "custom" job. Might be time to De-Customize it back to something a bit more practical.

Comment: Agreed with @Ecnerwal: if you have to cut it apart to get the toothbrush out, take the opportunity to install a new standard trap where the U-bend is easily removable.

Answer (score 5):

You could try using a pick-up or claw tool to reach down in the drain to grab it and pull it out.

Something like this [one at Amazon.com](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002RHP7TS).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Before you start taking things apart..... try this!
Get a dowel and your glue gun.  Dab hot glue onto tip of dowel, quickly put down drain onto toothbrush ( or whatever you've dropped down there) leave for a minute or 2 and pull dowel out!!

Nothing to take apart!  This probably would not work for a small item in the water but worth a try!!!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.

Comment: Heh, ended up paying a plumber to make a proper trap here.  But, very interesting suggestion, thanks :)